# ¿Como puedo ordenar las publicaciones por fecha en mi aplicación web en Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Hola tengo una aplicación web y estaba intentando ordenarlo por fecha mas reciente, es decir lo mas actual arriba y las fechas mas antigua abajo, pero por alguna razón en alguna computadora y móviles me ordena al revés y en otras ordena bien, lo raro es que en mi servidor local me anda bien, me ordena como yo quiero pero al momento de mostrarlo en la página web muestra como le había mencionado antes.

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Publicacion(models.Model):
    foto = models.ImageField()
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contenido = models.TextField()
    fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    contenido_largo = models.TextField(max_length=10000, default='', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

views.py

```
class ListarPublicaciones(ListView):
    model = Publicacion
    template_name = 'Publicacion/listarPublicaciones.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            pedidos = Pedido.objects.filter(cliente = self.request.user).aggregate(Sum('cantidad'))
            context['Pedido'] = pedidos
            context['object_list'] = Publicacion.objects.all().order_by('-fecha')
        return context
```

eh probado con order_by('-fecha__year','-fecha__month','-fecha__day')

html

```
<section class="py-5"><!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container"><!-- Container página principal -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
      <div class="panel">
        {% for p in object_list %}
          <div class="row">    
            <br>
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 text-center">
                  <a class="story-img" href="{% url 'publicacion:detallePublicacion' p.pk %}">
                <img src="{{p.foto.url}}" class="rounded" style="width: 250px;"></a>
              </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-9">
              <a class="subt" href="{% url 'publicacion:detallePublicacion' p.pk %}"><h2>{{p.titulo}}</h2></a>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <p class="texto">{{p.contenido|urlize}}</p>
                  <div class="redes list_op" style="text-align: right;">
                    <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled" >
                      {% if p.contenido_largo %}
                      <li>
                        <a class="plus" href="{% url 'publicacion:detallePublicacion' p.pk %}">Ver más</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>|</li>
                      {% endif %} 

                      <li>{{p.fecha.day}}-{{p.fecha.month}}-{{p.fecha.year}}</li>
                      <li>|</li>
                      <li>
                    <i class="fa fa-share" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 12px; color: #2c5d63;"></i> Compartir:
                    <a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://feriacultiva.com/publicaciones/detallepublicacion/{{p.pk}}"><img src="{% static 'icon/facebook.png' %}" border=0 height="25" class="facebook" /></a>
                    <a href="whatsapp://send?text=http:http://feriacultiva.com/publicaciones/detallepublicacion/{{p.pk}}" data-action="share/whatsapp/share"><img class="whatsapp" border="0" src="{% static 'icon/whatsapp.png' %}"></a>
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=¡Mira%20esta%20publicación%20de%20Feria%20Cultiva!&url=http://feriacultiva.com/publicaciones/detallepublicacion/{{p.pk}}" target="_blank"><img class="twitter" border="0" src="{% static 'icon/twitter.png' %}" height="25"></a>
                  </li>
                  
                    </ul>
                  </div>        
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                </div>
              </div>
              <br><br>
            </div>
          </div>
        <hr>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Pues no tiene sentido que así por así, en unos dispositivos ordene de tal manera y en otro de otra manera...

Answer (score 1):

Tal vez, intenta en el archivo de `models.py`; agregar la clase `Meta`, sería de esta manera:

```
class Meta:
    odering = ["-fecha"]
```